# Laravel 6 ForgotPasswordController doesn't send reset emails

Tags: php, laravel

I'm debugging a Laravel 6 application that isn't sending password reset emails to the users. All other emails sent by the application work fine and I've tried a different mail server without success. The application doesn't throw any errors in the logs and returns that the reset email was sent successfully if a valid email address was entered.

The reset emails should be sent by the default `ForgotPasswordController`. Only the methods `sendResetLinkResponse` and `sendResetLinkFailedResponse` were modified to some custom JSON responses.

```
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response()->json([...], 200);
    }

    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response()->json([...], 422);
    }
}
```

The endpoint calls the `sendResetLinkEmail` function, defined in the `SendsPasswortResetEmails` trait.

```
/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $this->credentials($request)
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

This function behaves like expected; with a valid email address, the overwritten `sendResetLinkResponse` method is called. Also, entries in the database table `password_resets` are generated.

The `User` model has the `CanResetPasswordContract` and the `CanResetPassword` trait, as described in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passwords. Also, the email column on the `User` model and in the database is called just `email`.

I've read in another post that `MAIL_FROM` attributes in the `.env` could cause some problems, but I think that`s not the problem in my case either, because all other emails that are sent by the application work fine.

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email@test.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Application"
```

I hope you can point me in the right direction to track down the issue. Thank you!

#### UPDATE

After I digged through the application code, I've found that the used notification implemented `ShouldQueue`. That was the reason why neither a message was sent nor an error was logged. For more details please see my reply below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I found the error by myself. I guess the solution is not generalizable, but maybe it helps some of you to search in the right direction.

Like described in the original question, the `sendResetLinkEmail` function was my last stop. This function is using the facade `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password` which is using `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker`.

```
// Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails::sendResetLinkEmail()
$response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
    $this->credentials($request)
);
```

The `PasswordBroker` has the following function:

```
// Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker
/**
 * Send a password reset link to a user.
 *
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return string
 */
public function sendResetLink(array $credentials)
{
    // First we will check to see if we found a user at the given credentials and
    // if we did not we will redirect back to this current URI with a piece of
    // "flash" data in the session to indicate to the developers the errors.
    $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

    if (is_null($user)) {
        return static::INVALID_USER;
    }

    if (method_exists($this->tokens, 'recentlyCreatedToken') &&
        $this->tokens->recentlyCreatedToken($user)) {
        return static::RESET_THROTTLED;
    }

    // Once we have the reset token, we are ready to send the message out to this
    // user with a link to reset their password. We will then redirect back to
    // the current URI having nothing set in the session to indicate errors.
    $user->sendPasswordResetNotification(
        $this->tokens->create($user)
    );

    return static::RESET_LINK_SENT;
}
```

So I've looked at:

```
// Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword
/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

And noticed through this, that the notification `ResetPasswordNotification` was published and implemented `ShouldQueue`.

```
class ResetPasswordNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue {}
```

Because no queue worker was running, the password reset notification was never sent but that's also the same reason why there was no error in the logs.

**Lessons learned**: Look at the `jobs` table first before you make your personal journey through the application code.